# How to create a thread in a specific channel with a Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use a channel for notifications, so i need my bot to start a conversation on said channel on demand. The documentation for Proactive bots is very poor, and it recommends me to use a method called `startReplyChain()` that doesn't exist.

The message has to be sent when a specific action is received by the bot.

This is what i have so far

```js
const { TeamsActivityHandler, CardFactory, TurnContext, TeamsInfo, Message } = require("botbuilder");

const TeamsBot = new TeamsActivityHandler()

TeamsBot.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
  let txt = context.activity.text;
  const removedMentionText = TurnContext.removeRecipientMention(
    context.activity
  );
  if (removedMentionText) {
    txt = removedMentionText.toLowerCase().replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim();
  }

  switch (txt) {
    case "update": {
      await sendUpdateMessage()
    }
  }

  await next();
});

async function sendUpdateMessage(action, context) {
  // Here the code to send the messages
  // I have the channel id and the bot is already added to the Team
  // Just leaves figuring out how to send the message
  
  return { statusCode: 200 };
}
```

Comment: Is the bot replying in the same channel that the mention was received on? Or is it sending the message possibly to a different team/channel altogether?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.